# jQuery animate not working firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, firefox

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('a[href*=#]').click(function(){

        if ($window_width > 1000 ) {
            var offset = 96;
        } else {
            var offset = 0;
        }

        jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: jQuery('[name="' + jQuery(this).attr('href').substr(1) + '"]').offset().top - offset
        }, 500);

        return false;
    });

});
```

This code is supposed to animate the transition when a user clicks on a link to an anchor on the same page. It works in every browser except Firefox, and the same code works on a different page of the same website in Firefox (!?).

In Firefox, it doesn't take the user to the anchor tag unless I remove the "return false;" - in which case it skips to the anchor tag without animating, but continues to work normally in other browsers.

Any ideas? There are no errors in my console.

**- Edit -**

I discovered another oddity. The anchor animation works before the page is fully loaded and then it stops working. I should also mention that this is a Wordpress site with lots of scripts being loaded.

Here is an example of what my anchor tags look like.
    `<a href="#self-managed">Self-Service</a>`
    `<a name="self-managed"></a>`

Comment: Have your tried cleaning up Firefox history and cache?

Comment: Also, it would help if you demonstrate with a live example!

Comment: Can you show us the anchor tag you are using in your page?

Comment: I have tried clearing history and caches.A link to the page in question: http://www.l2tmedia.com/toyota/
And the page in which the same code works (on the view openings button): http://www.l2tmedia.com/careers/